# Python - Storing the values of CSV file in List

Tags: python, csv

I want to store the values of first row of csv file into a list. Does anyone know how to do it.

For example:
my `csv` file contains data:

```
0.1777
0.9999
0.5600
```

and i want to store it in a list

```
list1 = ['0.1777','0.9999','0.5600']
```

Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use:

```
my_list = open('some_file.csv', 'r').read().split("\n")
print my_list
# ['0.1777', '0.9999', '0.5600']
```